# Как убрать сообщение 'Ошибка взаимодействия'?

Tags: disnake

При использовании команды !help вылазит список, после нажатия на нужную категорию оригинальное сообщение меняется и под списком пишет "Ошибка взаимодействия", хотя всё нормально работает.
Помогите пожалуйста убрать это сообщение.

```
class Dropdown(disnake.ui.StringSelect):
    def __init__(self):
        options = [
            disnake.SelectOption(
                label="Экономика", emoji=""
            ),
            disnake.SelectOption(
                label="Фан", emoji=""
            ),
            disnake.SelectOption(
                label="Информация", emoji=""
            ),
            disnake.SelectOption(
                label="Музыка", description="Скоро", emoji="⏰"
            ),
        ]
        super().__init__(
            placeholder="",
            min_values=1,
            max_values=1,
            options=options,
        )

    async def callback(self, inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        economy = disnake.Embed(title='Экономика\n Префикс бота - !', description='> **baltop** - топ пользователей.\n\n> **balance** - проверить свой баланс.\n\n> **pay** - перевод другому пользователю.\n\n> **shop** - магазин сервера.\n\n> **buy** - купить предмет.\n\n> **work** - заработать денег.', color=disnake.Color.dark_blue())
        fun = disnake.Embed(title='Фан', description='> **avatar** - аватарка пользователя.\n\n> **hug** - обнять пользователя.\n\n> **kiss** - поцеловать пользователя.\n\n> **dice** - задать костям судьбы вопрос.', color=disnake.Color.dark_blue())
        info = disnake.Embed(title='', description='', color=disnake.Color.dark_blue())
        if self.values[0] == 'Экономика':
            await inter.message.edit(embed=economy, content=None)
            self.stop()
        if self.values[0] == 'Фан':
            await inter.message.edit(embed=fun, content=None)
            self.stop()
        if self.values[0] == 'Информация':
            await inter.message.edit(content='None')
            dropdown = self.view.children[0]
            dropdown.options = []


class DropdownView(disnake.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_item(Dropdown())

class InfoCommands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def help(self, ctx):
        view = DropdownView()
        embed= disnake.Embed(color=disnake.Color.dark_blue())
        embed.add_field(name='Информационное окно', value='   ', inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)
```